# Typescript function return type depending on number or type of arguments

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function that should return different types depending on the number and type of arguments. How would I describe this in TypeScript?

```
function foo(t: number): string
function foo(t: number, s: string): boolean {
   return typeof s === 'string' ? true : 'false';
}
```

In words: the function `foo` returns a `string` when invoked with a `number` argument and returns a `boolean` when invoked with a `number` and a `string` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the overload of your function + change the implementation, like :

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUUBciwgLYBGApgE4A0iAztpVCTGAOYCU2BqANkQIZgDcAKAGhIsBMlQZsuQqVZU6DRoOHho8JCnRYc+YuSoB+Goqbza9JogA+AAvZwuvRAG8BiDySJQQJJJUQAQgBeYMQANzgYABNEAAZEQ0Q6ECJEbAByYG4OSiIMwQBfIQgEWgjuEgBGRDCtNABWOOZBUrBy8MqAJlqJdCaKDIsMlqA)

```
function foo(t: number, s: string): boolean;

function foo(t: number): string;

function foo(t: number, s?: string): string | boolean {
   return s !== void 0 ? true : 'false';
}

const var1 = foo(50);
const var2 = foo(50, 'str');
```

---

In this way, TypeScript will be able to define which is the correct type of your variable depending on the number of parameter of your function.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't have that level of granularity. You can say:

```
function foo(t: number, s?: string): string | boolean
```

…in which it takes an *optional* second argument and returns either a string or a boolean, but if you want to make the return value type conditional on the arguments then you would need to define two seperate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! TypeScript don't support this as far as my experience go.
What you could do is to set the return type to a `this | that` type.
This means "return type is `this` or `that`"

```
function foo(t: number, s: string): string | boolean {}
```

In my team at work we generally try to avoid the `this | that` approach because it can be an added source of bugs.

My recommendation is two functions with specific return types, if this is possible in your application.

```
function getFoo(t: number): string {}

function isFoo(t: number, s: string): boolean {}
```